# columns not fitting into grid

Tags: compass-sass, blueprint-css

I just started using compass blueprint and I'm making a simple frame with the following:

```
$blueprint_grid_columns: 12;
$blueprint_grid_width: 60px;
$blueprint-grid-margin: 20px;

@import "blueprint";

.frame {
  @include container;
  .header{
    @include column(12);
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
  }
  .left_bar{
    @include column(1);
    background:#ccc;
    height:450px;
  }
  .content{
    @include column(10);
    background: #000;
    height:450px;
  }
  .right_bar{
    @include column(1);
    backgrounf:#ccc
    height:450px;
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<body>
  <div class='frame'>

    <div class='header'>
    </div> <!-- end header -->

    <div class='left_bar'>
    </div> <!-- end left_bar -->

    <div class='content'>
    </div> <!-- end content -->

    <div class='right_bar'>  
    </div> <!-- end right_bar -->

  </div> <!-- end frame -->
</body>
```

The right_bar isn't fitting into the space for the last column but rather appearing exactly under the left_bar. Can anyone tell me why? Any help greatly appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `true` to the header and right_bar classes:

```
.header{
  @include column(12, true);

....
.right_bar{
  @include column(1, true);
```

This lets compass know that it's the last column, and that the margin needs to be zeroed out.

Comment: To expand on the question, I want to have 3 areas within the content div (left_content, middle_content and right_content). The content div has 10 columns so I've given 2+6+2 to the nested divs.

I'm having the same problem with right_content. Adding true as an arg makes no difference. Is this because its nested?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out. I added some borders that pushed the grid out of whack a bit. I fixed it by overriding widths but it seems a bit hacky. Is there a blueprint way to take borders into account?